# Broken App Store Connect listing is preventing any changes, how can I fix it?

Tags: app-store-connect

My app on App Store Connect has a third picture for the iPad Pro which hasn't uploaded.

[image: Broken upload]

Until App Store Connect thinks that this file has finished uploading, or it's removed, I can't make any changes.  Submitting another version for review results in an error saying that pictures are still being uploaded.

Is there something I can do to fix this, or have I encountered a very weird App Store Connect bug?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying you can't delete or add a new image until this upload has completed?

Comment: No, I can't *add any updates to my app* until that image upload has completed.  Which it never will because its stuck on the uploading state between reboots etc.

Comment: I've never seen that before.  The only way to fix might be to contact Apple to do something on their end.